# Routing with in the Module in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular9

[enter image description here][1][I am lazy loading the user module  and getting login page on empty path in user.routing , but unable to navigate from login to signup through router.navigate
User is a sub module and (login,signup, forgot) are components in user module, it is working if i import user Module in App Module other wise not working with router.navigate and other directives]

```
App Structure:
app
|-(appModule.ts,app.component.ts,app.component.html)
|-user
   |-[UserModule.ts,user-routing.ts]
   |-loginComponent
   |-signupComponent
   |-forgotComponent

UserModule:
const routes: Routes = [     
         { path: '', component: LoginComponent },     
         { path: 'signup', pathMatch:'full',component: SignupComponent },    
         { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent } 
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, SignupComponent, ForgotComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})

AppRouting:
export const routes: Routes = [   
{ path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' ,loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)},

 ]
```

Comment: Your lazy-loaded module must have its own `router-outlet`.

Comment: BTW, having a parent route named after `login` in this case sounds a little bit strange, because you'd also have a `login/forgot` and `login/signup`. Don't you think it would be better if you call it `auth` or `user` (it's loading the `UserModule`)

Comment: i just named it for example purposes and the problem was solved by removing pathMatch: full in lazy loading  route, didnt know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma618283966433166)

If you're lazy loading the user module, I suggest you have a routing component:

```html
@Component({
  selector: `user-routing-component`,
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class UserRoutingComponent {}
```

Then, you could do this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserRoutingComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: LoginComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'signup',
            component: SignupComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'forgot',
            component: ForgotComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ], // imports,
  declarations: [
    UserRoutingComponent, 
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    ForgotComponent
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

The parent route would be like this:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('PATH/TO/USER/MODULE/user.module')
        .then(m => m.UserModule)
  }
])
```

Now you have these routes:

- login
- login/forgot
- login/signup

Don't you think it would be better to have:

- auth/login
- auth/forgot
- auth/signup

Or something like that?

Comment: Added a stackblitz demo in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was solved by removing pathMatch: full in lazy loading route,  please share me the reason if possible.

Comment: Because you have sub routes. If `x` is the only route you don't need to use `pathMatch='full'`. But if you have subroutes, like `x/route1`, `x/route2`, and you want to load a component, or redirect, when the path `x` appears alone, you must specify `pathMatch='full'` for that route.